# How to specify the library of the operator %+% such as pkg:: or pkg:::

Tags: r, ggplot2

The operator `%+%` are used in two packages, i.e., `ggplot2` and `crayou`.

The function `%+%` in `crayon` sometimes not work, I think the operator `%+%` are considered in `ggplot2`.  I try to identify by `crayon::%+%` but this does not work.

```
cat(green(
 'I am a green line ' %+%
 blue$underline$bold('with a blue substring') %+%
 ' that becomes green again!'
))
```

----  based on comments : I think the following error occur for my miss understanding--------

I try to run the following code using `crayon::(backtick)%+%(backtick)` instead of `%+%`

```
cat(green(
    'I am a green line ' crayon::`%+%`
        blue$underline$bold('with a blue substring') crayon::`%+%`
        ' that becomes green again!'
))
```

But the following error occurs:

```
  > cat(green(
+     'I am a green line ' crayon::`%+%`
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"cat(green(
    'I am a green line ' crayon"
>         blue$underline$bold('with a blue substring') crayon::`%+%`
Error: unexpected symbol in "        blue$underline$bold('with a blue substring') crayon"
>         ' that becomes green again!'
[1] " that becomes green again!"
> ))
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"
```

Comment: try it with backticks, e.g.  ggplot2::(backtick)%+%(backtick) -- unfortunately if I use backtick in comments it converts to code formating

Comment: The `import` package also has a mechanism to deal with this kind of situation, with `import::from(ggplot2, "+")` for example.

Comment: `crayon::\`%+%\`` (just put backslashes before the backtick @gfgm)

Comment: Thank you @gfgm,and @hrbrmstr.  I try the code `crayon::`%+%`, however it does not go well.

Comment: Thank you  @meriops,  I develop some package, so I  can understand what you say and I think  `#'@importFrom crayon %+%` may give the same solution ? Thank you for letting me the way use `library(import")`, I did not know this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to not `library(crayon)` or `requireNamespace(crayon)` and fully qualify all `crayon` references:

```
cat(crayon::green(
  'I am a green line ' %c+%
    crayon::blue$underline$bold('with a blue substring') crayon::`%+%`
    ' that becomes green again!'
))
```

That's annoying, though. So, you can also hand-import *and rename* things you need *without the need for a separate, non-core package*:

```
`%c+%` <- getFromNamespace("%+%", "crayon") # changed to not break other things
green <- getFromNamespace("green", "crayon")
blue <- getFromNamespace("blue", "crayon")

cat(green(
  'I am a green line ' %c+%
    blue$underline$bold('with a blue substring') %c+%
    ' that becomes green again!'
))
```

Comment: I can’t think of such good codes. Allow me to use your code in my package.

Comment: Note that the first code of `@hrbrmstr `'s  does not go well ( even if after fixing from $%c+%$ to $%+%$. So, as I said in above comment,  `crayon::(backtick)%+%(backtick) ` does not go well.

Comment: You are doing something amiss then

Comment: So many people suggest the code  `crayon::(backtick)%+%(backtick)`,  it would go well in their PC.  I think I am somthing wrong, but I cannot  come up.

Comment: I guess I'd also add "what are these superfluous colors adding to your message that plaintext can't convey?" but ultra-sensitive SO moderators might interpret that as being mean (so I can't "win" either way)

Comment: So the reason why I want to use color is to emphasis the important text in my outputs, since my package implements some complex statistical model, which has many estimates.  Anyway, like you said, using `getFromNamespace`, it goes, well. I appreciate  you very very much !!